# Vis.js: how to access the network inside an event handler?

Tags: javascript, vis.js, vis.js-network

I'd like to use vis.js for displaying and editing a graph (hence storing its nodes, edges and options). To implement this, I need to save changes of the network (=graph) on various events. On of them is rearranging via drag and drop.

Now, there's an `on` method which supports the `dragEnd` event meaning I can do stuff like

```
network.on("dragEnd",saveToTiddlerAfterDragging);
```

However [what's passed to the handler](http://visjs.org/docs/network/#Events) is this object:

```
{
  nodes: [Array of selected nodeIds],
  edges: [Array of selected edgeIds],
  event: [Object] original _ event,
  pointer: {
    DOM: {x:pointer_x, y:pointer_y},
    canvas: {x:canvas_x, y:canvas_y}
  }
}
```

Seems like there's no reference of the `network` itself. So how to access it? I'd like to define `saveToTiddlerAfterDragging` in another scope than `network` itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, while reading docs and writing the question, I wild-guessed that the `network` is actually `this` in the event handler context. Not sure if it's true for all the event handlers but works with the `dragEnd` one.