# Vis.js: how to access the network inside an addNode helper without using a closure?

Tags: javascript, vis.js, vis.js-network

Un[like event handlers in vis.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46101929/vis-js-how-to-access-the-network-inside-an-event-handler/46101930), [`manipulation`](http://visjs.org/docs/network/manipulation.html) helpers (`addNode` etc) don't provide a reference to the `network` or its DOM container itself. Is there a way to access either one if `addNode` and `network` itself should be defined in different scopes so that closure can't be used?

*Context.* I'm implementing a simple graph editor in TiddlyWiki Classic using vis.js. The peculiar thing is there can be multiple networks displayed at a time and their ids are generated so they do not to conflict and a user doesn't have to set those manually. On the other hand, it's desirable to allow user set arbitrary manipulation handlers and a usual need is to get the network's container with the "unknown"=random id (it's available from network itself as `network.body.container`, but I failed to get `network` inside `addNode`).

PS I wonder how to patch vis.js itself since `this` inside `addNode` is equal to the `manipulation` property of `options` which seems totally useless. Looks like in [ManipulationSystem.js](https://github.com/almende/vis/blob/master/lib/network/modules/ManipulationSystem.js) calling `this.options.addNode` should be made with `call`: instead of

```
    this.options.addNode(defaultData, (finalizedData) => {
```

(line 1156) should be

```
    this.options.addNode.call(this, defaultData, (finalizedData) => {
```

PPS while considering making a fork/pull request, I've found out that it's clear where to add this context to `addNode` (line 1156), `addEdge` (line 1186), `editEdge` (1220) but not `editNode`. Where is it?

Comment: this I am interested in. Do you mean that you can access the nodes or edges information from the manipulation helpers? for instance I would like to get the group of the target node (addEdge event). Did you achieve this? can you please be more specific about it?

Comment: finally managed to make it work as I wish: in vis.js (line 59423) : `var defaultData = { id: this.edgeBeingEditedId, from: sourceNodeId, to: targetNodeId, infos: this.body.data };`
but I'm not sure, is there any reason why this should not be done this way?